# Funky weasel is jiggy wit it

Tags: word-usage

It is a name of Linux kernel `2.6.25-rc2–2.6.25–`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_kernel_names

What exactly means `is jiggy wit it`?

Comment: It's a 90s catchphrase, made popular by a Will Smith song, with a variety of meanings, many vulgar.

Comment: Could you say it in another way?

Comment: @AnomalousAwe It's slang. In this context it doesn't mean much of anything; taking a look at that list, they're all pretty random. They took a slang phrase that sounded funny and slapped the name on. I think that's about as in-depth as this goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Is jiggy wit[h] it” basically means “dances” or perhaps more specifically “emulates the gyrations and footwork from [the video for *Gettin’ Jiggy wit’ it*](http://vimeo.com/67045476)” and presumably derives (however distantly) from “jig”:

> **jig**
> <sup>noun</sup>
> 1. a lively dance with leaping movements.
> <sub>Source: [Google - define “jig”](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+jig&oq=define+jig)</sub>

Here are the lyrics of the song that popularized this phrasing, with explanations of various lines:
http://rapgenius.com/Will-smith-gettin-jiggy-with-it-lyrics

As StoneyB mentions, the term carries overt sexual connotations. In fact, thefreedictionary.com says:

> **jiggy** (ˈdʒɪɡɪ)
> <sup>adj</sup>
> 1. **get jiggy with** - to have sexual relations with
> <sub>Source: [thefreedictionary.com definition for “jiggy”](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jiggy)</sub>

In my opinion, it’s a fairly light-hearted term, usually used as a euphemism for intercourse and/or intercourse-like behavior. I’d say: don’t write it in formal writing, don’t say it to proper people.

Comment: At the end, kernel name is "Funky weasel has sexual intercourse with it". (: With kernel?

Comment: @Anomalous It's impossible to say for sure without asking the author, but as far as this phrase goes, the “it” in question is usually extremely generalized. (This use is distinct from the related possibility of naming something or someone, as in “Funky Weasel got jiggy wit _Mrs. Weasel.”)_ It may be a more accurate interpretation to say “Funky weasel is being sexual” basically thinking of the “it” as the subject's entire mode of existence.

Comment: I can hardly believe I was tricked into considering the sex-life of a Linux kernel. And it's only Monday morning :(